# Mysql - joined table must match condition for all dates

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `resources` and `booking_sums`. I want to get resources that for a certain date range, all of the available time slots for each date are fully booked. But this proved to be very difficult.

I have a `booking sums` table, which stores dates and three time slots (`event_time`) for each date.

```
booking_sums
--------------
    event_date               (date)
    event_time               (1-3)
    resource id
    sum_booked
    free_seats_left
```

I provide an `event date` range, and get resources that meet this condition:

- for every event_date there should exist entries for all three event_times (1,2 and 3) and each entry should have seats_left = 0
- all event dates in the date range must match the above condition.

My problem is that if only one date matches the condition, i still get the resource.

So if I have these booking_sums:

```
id  |  event_date  |   event_time  |  resource_id  |  sum_booked  |  free_seats_left  |
id  |  2019-09-18  |        1      |      122      |      250     |        0    |
id  |  2019-09-18  |        2      |      122      |      250     |        0    |
id  |  2019-09-19  |        1      |      122      |      250     |        0    |
id  |  2019-09-19  |        2      |      122      |      250     |        0    |
id  |  2019-09-19  |        3      |      122      |      250     |        0    |
```

the date 2019-09-19 matches the condition, but 2019-09-18 doesn't. So if 2019-09-18 is included in the date range, we shouldnt get that result - but I still get it. 
Here is my query:

```
SELECT distinct r.* FROM resources r
INNER JOIN bookings_sums bs1
ON r.id = bs1.resource_id  
WHERE EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM bookings_sums 
      where event_time = 1
      AND resource_id = r.id 
      AND event_date = bs1.event_date 
      AND free_seats_left = 0
    )
AND EXISTS(  SELECT 1 FROM bookings_sums where event_time = 2 AND resource_id = r.id 
       AND event_date = bs1.event_date AND free_seats_left = 0)
AND EXISTS(  SELECT 1 FROM bookings_sums where event_time = 3 AND resource_id = r.id 
       AND event_date = bs1.event_date AND free_seats_left = 0) 

AND bs1.event_date BETWEEN '2019-09-18' AND '2019-09-19'
```

**Edit**:
Here is a fiddle: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eb015/1)

**Edit2**:
From the suggested answer below which worked, I did some adjustments to make it a bit simpler, which seems to work:

```
 SELECT r.id, 
        r.title
  FROM resources r
  INNER JOIN bookings_sums bs     
    ON r.id = bs.resource_id 
    AND bs.resource_id = r.id 
    AND bs.event_date 
    BETWEEN '2019-09-19' AND '2019-09-19' AND bs.free_seats_left = 0
  GROUP BY r.id, r.title
  HAVING COUNT(bs.id) = (DATEDIFF('2019-09-19', '2019-09-19') + 1) * 3
```

(And instead of the DATEDIFF I could use php and put in a number directly in my case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it without the sub query.

```
SELECT r.*
FROM resources r
INNER JOIN bookings_sums bs1
ON r.id = bs1.resource_id
AND bs1.resource_id = r.id
AND bs1.event_date = bs1.event_date
AND bs1.free_seats_left = 0
GROUP BY r......
HAVING SUM(bs.id) = 3
AND bs1.event_date BETWEEN '2019-09-18' AND '2019-09-19'
```

You will need to specify all the columns on the resources table in the GROUP BY query.

Or just doing 3 joins

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM resources r
INNER JOIN bookings_sums bs1     ON r.id = bs1.resource_id  AND bs1.event_time = 1 AND bs1.resource_id = r.id AND bs1.free_seats_left = 0
INNER JOIN bookings_sums bs2     ON r.id = bs2.resource_id  AND bs2.event_time = 2 AND bs2.resource_id = r.id AND bs2.event_date = bs1.event_date AND bs2.free_seats_left = 0
INNER JOIN bookings_sums bs3     ON r.id = bs3.resource_id  AND bs3.event_time = 3 AND bs3.resource_id = r.id AND bs3.event_date = bs1.event_date AND bs3.free_seats_left = 0
WHERE bs1.event_date BETWEEN '2019-09-18' AND '2019-09-19'
```

---

EDIT

This gives you what you need, but there must be a tidier way to do it.

```
SELECT id,
        title
FROM
(
  SELECT r.id, 
        r.title , 
        sub0.day_cnt
  FROM resources r
  CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT DATEDIFF('2019-09-19', '2019-09-18') + 1 AS day_cnt
  ) sub0
  INNER JOIN bookings_sums bs     ON r.id = bs.resource_id AND bs.resource_id = r.id AND bs.event_date BETWEEN '2019-09-18' AND '2019-09-19' AND bs.free_seats_left = 0
  GROUP BY r.id, r.title
  HAVING COUNT(bs.id) = sub0.day_cnt * 3
) sub1;
```

Comment: The first one complained about  bs1.event_date, so I added it to the select and to the group by, but I get no results (if I only put 2019-09-19 I should get resource 122). The other query gives me 122 each time, although it shouldnt because at 2019-09-18 there are only 2 event times.

Comment: @Galivan - can you put up the actual table declares and the insert statements for a bit of data. Then I can past it in and test it.

Comment: Yes , now I have one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eb015/1 . I may have misunderstood what to put where you wrote "GROUP BY r......".

Comment: @Galivan - this works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eb015/28 , but I am sure I am missing a better way to do it.

Comment: very awesome, thanks. I did a simplification of your query that seems to work(?), I got rid of the cross join, because then I can convert this to laravel code (which lacks a "crossJoinSub" method) - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eb015/32 . If you think it works too, you could add that code to the answer.

Comment: @Galivan - if you can work out the date difference in advance then easy to remove that subquery.